# How to make python check EACH value

Tags: python, string, list

I am working on this function and I want to Return a list of the elements of L that end with the specified token in the order they appear in the original list.

```
def has_last_token(s,word):
""" (list of str, str) -> list of str

Return a list of the elements of L that end with the specified token in the order they appear in the original list.

>>> has_last_token(['one,fat,black,cat', 'one,tiny,red,fish', 'two,thin,blue,fish'], 'fish')
['one,tiny,red,fish', 'two,thin,blue,fish']
"""
for ch in s:
    ch = ch.replace(',' , ' ')
    if word in ch:
        return ch
```

So I know that when I run the code and test out the example I provided, it checks through

```
'one,fat,black,cat'
```

and sees that the word is not in it and then continues to check the next value which is

```
'one,tiny,red,fish'
```

Here it recognizes the word fish and outputs it. But the code doesn't check for the last input which is also valid. How can I make it check all values rather then just check until it sees one valid output?

expected output

```
>>> has_last_token(['one,fat,black,cat', 'one,tiny,red,fish', 'two,thin,blue,fish'], 'fish')
>>> ['one,tiny,red,fish', 'two,thin,blue,fish']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question altering your code and your logic the least I can, in case you understand the answer better this way.

If you `return ch`, you'll immediately terminate the function.

One way to accomplish what you want is to simply declare a `list` before your loop and then append the items you want to that list accordingly. The return value would be that list, like this:

```
def has_last_token(s, word):
    result = []
    for ch in s:
        if ch.endswith(word):  # this will check only the string's tail
            result.append(ch)
    return result
```

PS: That `ch.replace()` is unnecessary according to the function's docstring

Comment: And how would I check the list to see if the word is at the end of items?

Comment: Then you would replace  `if word in ch:` with `if ch.endswith(word):` (If I correctly understood what you want). I just edited the answer to show it.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the first match and this exits the function. You want to either yield from the loop (creating a generator) or build a list and return that. I would just use `endswith` in a list comprehension. I'd also rename things to make it clear what's what.

```
def has_last_token(words_list, token):
    return [words for words in words_list if words.endswith(token)]
```

Comment: Might this not fail if the final word itself ends with `word` but was not `word` e.g. `'two,thin,bluefish'`? This should not match?

Comment: @PaulRooney But the function says "last token",  not "last word", right?

Comment: @yLaguardia I'm posing a question rather than stating its wrong. Even though the words `token` and `word` are used pretty much interchangeably by the OP and to my mind using token in the lexical sense it makes more sense that tokens are the things delimited by the commas.

Comment: @PaulRooney I was also asking a question! That's why I ended it with "right?" to show my uncertainty :)

Comment: Sure I guess only the OP can authoritatively answer. If they are happy, it must be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `rsplit` to split the last token from the rest of the string. If you pass the second argument as 1 (could use named argument `maxsplit` in py3 but py2 doesn't like it) it stops after one split, which is all we need here.

You can then use `filter` rather than an explicit loop to check each string has `word` as its final token and return a list of only those strings which do have `word` as their final token.

```
def has_last_token(L, word):
      return filter(lambda s: s.rsplit(',', 1)[-1] == word, L)

result = has_last_token(['one,fat,black,cat',
                           'one,tiny,red,fish',
                           'two,thin,blue,fish',
                           'two,thin,bluefish',
                           'nocommas'], 'fish')

for res in result:
    print(res)
```

Output:

> one,tiny,red,fish
>   two,thin,blue,fish